# Java performance on GNU/Linux

Tags: java, linux

I wrote a Java application that needs to run on both Windows and GNU/Linux, and it works. The only problem I had is that on GNU/Linux it uses A LOT more CPU than Windows, about 15 times more!
It also takes several seconds to start. Is there something I can do about it?
Currently I'm using this command line: -XX:CompileThreshold=5

Thanks

Comment: You need to show some code or some profiler output.

Comment: well, that's quite a lot of code to post. The only unusual thing I see in the profiler is that the main method takes 2 seconds to execute, and all it does is open a sound channel to see if there's a sound card.

Answer (score 1):

I googled around a bit and found this flag for Java 7 and later:

```
    -XX:+TieredCompilation
```

It removed the slow startup and the CPU abuse is much lower now

Comment: Please do some research on why this works better now so the answer gets more useful for future readers.

Comment: well, apparently, this flag speeds things up by compiling "partially" and only when necessary "based on profiler data". i guess it's like -XX:CompileThreshold=5 but with an automatically generated parameter instead of 5. no idea what they mean by "compiling partially", maybe it's x86 with some parts of bytecode?